# How can I control each icon independently if they all have the same class

Tags: html, css

I want the icon in the first box to be white, and the other boxes to be a different color.
[this is the boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvbJX.png)

```css
.long-arrow-right {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
 
}
.fa.fa-long-arrow-right:before {
  content: "\f30b";
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
  <span class="long-arrow-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

Comment: Additional specificity, another class, an ID or a specific selector.

Comment: Add nth-child concept u can control color based on nth element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want another color on your first icon, you can use :first-of-type

```css
.myClass {
  color: blue;
}

.myClass:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="myClass">1</p>
<p class="myClass">2</p>
<p class="myClass">3</p>
```

Another solution is not possible (IMO), you cannot control elements with same class, because you cannot identify them. You have to add **unique** ID.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add Many Ways

1. You can use nth-child concept
2. You can use class for active element
3. You can use active ID and you can change color

   1. ways

   ```css
   .long-arrow-right {
   width: 100%;
   text-align: right;
   }

   .fa.fa-long-arrow-right:before {
   content: "\f30b";
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #000;
   }
   .long-arrow-right:first-child .fa.fa-long-arrow-right:before{
   color:red;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <span class="long-arrow-right">
   <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </span>

   <span class="long-arrow-right">
   <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </span>
   <span class="long-arrow-right">
   <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </span>
   ```

2.way

```css
.long-arrow-right {
width: 100%;
text-align: right;
}

.fa.fa-long-arrow-right:before {
content: "\f30b";
font-size: 20px;
color: #000;
}
.fa.fa-long-arrow-right.active:before{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<span class="long-arrow-right">
<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right active" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>

<span class="long-arrow-right">
<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
<span class="long-arrow-right">
<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
```